# Tag merge request: [permissions] and [permisions]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

It's definitely a typo, so [permisions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permisions) should be merged with [permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permissions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds reasonable to me. Done.